# How do I use "\r" in 2 lines at the same time c#

Tags: c#

I want to be able to update 2 lines at the same time.

E.g

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
Console.Write("\rNumber 1 - {0}",i);
Console.Write("\rNumber 2 - {0}",i);
}
```

But it just just prints over the first Write line.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be looking for a way to display several lines in a console, and overwrite them periodically. To do that, you need to place the cursor back to the same position every time.

The function to do that is [Console.SetCursorPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 2) {
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
    Console.WriteLine("Number 1: {0}", i);
    Console.WriteLine("Number 2: {0}", i + 1);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Console WriteLine... or \n

Use a line break with \n

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Console.Write("\rNumber 1 - {0} \n",i);
    Console.Write("\rNumber 2 - {0}",i);
}
```

Or Console.WriteLine

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number 1 - {0}",i);
    Console.WriteLine("Number 2 - {0}",i);
}
```

---

Try this miscelaneous

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\rNumber 1 - {0} \r\n",i);
    Console.WriteLine("\rNumber 2 - {0} \r\n",i);
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work for me :/. Just updates Number 2 and keeps printing Number 1 before it

Comment: The first solution prints lots of Number 1s and 1 number 2 and the second one prints one after the other as if \r wasn't there

Comment: @SamHall Using `WriteLine`, just get rid of those `\r`.

Comment: I only want there to be 2 lines by the end of the for loop, this solution has 200 because it prints every line for every loop

Comment: You're aware the loop will complete instantaneously and you'll only see the result of the  last iteration?

Comment: yeah I have a Thread.Sleep(100) in my code but I didn't include that in the post

Comment: The final solution posted prints the same as before but with a blank line between each Console.WriteLine

Comment: Is clearing the console the only way because there is information before that I want to keep that I dont want to wipe

Comment: @SamHall Please edit your question and show what result you hope to obtain

Answer (score 0):

\r move the cursor to the start of the current line and starts to overwrite the previous text

\n makes a new line

if you want to overwrite your previous line then you are alredy right

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   Console.Write("\rNumber 1 - " +i.ToString());
   Console.Write("\rNumber 2 - "+i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to only have 2 lines printed and just update the "i" variable, this solution prints Number 1 followed by Number 2 followed by Number 1 etc on multiple different lines

Comment: i changed my answer according to youy comment

Comment: This is so close to what I want thank you! But I would like each Console.Write to be on individual lines and using Console.WriteLine seems to break it.